# Dividing counts on db2?

Tags: sql, math, count, db2, division

Hello I have a query where I am pulling the count of new hires who have downloaded our app and the count of new hires.

I am trying to divide the two to find the percentage of those who have downloaded the app

but whenever I run my query my result is 0 
both `data` and `driver_id` are varchar
here is my query

```
SELECT ROUND(COUNT(DATA) / (
            SELECT COUNT(D2.DRIVER_ID)
            FROM DRIVER D2
            WHERE ACTIVE_IN_DISP = 'True'
                AND START_DATE >= '10/1/2015'
            ), 4)
FROM CUSTOM_DATA C
    ,DRIVER D
WHERE CUSTDEF_ID = '50'
    AND SRC_TABLE_KEY = DRIVER_ID
    AND ACTIVE_IN_DISP = 'True'
    AND START_DATE >= '10/1/2015'
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: I forget to mention the count for data is 10 and the count for driver_id is 64

Comment: Note, by the way, that implicit joins (having two tables in the from clause) is a deprecated syntax, and it's recommended to switch to the modern, explicit, syntax: Learn how to use explicit join syntax. Aaron Bertrand did some [**writting**](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you are getting truncate to `INT`

convert your data to float before the division

```
SELECT ROUND(  COUNT(DATA) *1.0 /
              (SELECT COUNT(D2.DRIVER_ID)
              ....
```

Comment: remember accept this answer if help you with your question

Comment: yEAH i am trying but i have to wait like 30 seconds I have been coming back and forth to make sure i give you the credit you deserve!

Answer (score 1):

Just use conditional aggregation.  It is easier and less prone to error:

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN CUSTDEF_ID = '50' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0
                 END), 4)
FROM CUSTOM_DATA C JOIN
     DRIVER D
     ON SRC_TABLE_KEY = DRIVER_ID
WHERE ACTIVE_IN_DISP = 'True' AND
      START_DATE >= '2015-10-01';
```

Not having to repeat the logic in the `WHERE` using a subquery makes the query much less prone to error.  Plus, it is probably faster to get rid of the subquery as well.